# GitHub Action: No event is appearing, is workflow running?

Tags: github, workflow, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I've added to my repository a [workflow](https://github.com/Cl00e9ment/open-elevation/blob/d49f44e28cf8e873bbb05fd2b705aa5efbd7fec0/.github/workflows/workflow.yml) inspired from https://henry.wang/2019/12/05/arm-dockerhub.html
The repository is public so you can see the "Action" tab [here](https://github.com/Cl00e9ment/open-elevation/actions).

There were a typo error in the file:
[image: workflow failed]

So I fixed it and [pushed the fix](https://github.com/Cl00e9ment/open-elevation/commit/d49f44e28cf8e873bbb05fd2b705aa5efbd7fec0). However no new event is appearing: there is only the previous "fail" event as you can see above.

Does this mean that the worklow is running and is not terminated or does it mean the workflow wasn't started?
If it wasn't started what did I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just choosed the wrong branch.

Changed the workflow file from

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
# ...
```

to

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - auto-build
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for all branches:

```
on: [push]
```

You can find more in the official doc
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on

```
# Example: Using a list of events
# Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events
on: [push, pull_request]
```